# Build react element as string

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically build a React element.

```
    let section = <span>Home> {header.section}</span>
    ...
    section += <span> > {location.title}</span>

    return (section)
```

If I don't try and add anything it works fine, when I do the above I get `[object Object][object Object]`

How do I go about building a React element dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
let section = [<span key={1}>Home> {header.section}</span>]
....
section.push(<span key={2}> {location.title}</span>)

return section
```

and in and in render

```
<div>{section}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare section with empty array and keep pushing the elements you want to and then use map to render it :)

```
   ######### Process data here #########
   let section = [];
   section.push(<span>Home > Company Name</span>);
   section.push(<span>About us > Company Features</span>);

    ######### To render using map  #########
   const renderSection = section.map((val, idx) =>{
        return (val);
    })


    ######### To Display  #########
  {renderSection}
```

Hope this helps :)